# How to Display an ItemTemplate and Alternating ItemTemplate Side-by-Side in a Gridview?

Tags: html, css, asp.net

I have a "Reports" page that will display a dynamic number of buttons (formatted ASP:Hyperlinks) based on how many active reports are in a table. I can get everything to work except for the display I'm aiming for. I would like to see my buttons side by side (left is an "ItemTemplate" and right is an "AlternatingItemTemplate").

**HTML Code:**

```
<asp:Panel runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gv_Reports" runat="server" DataKeyField="ReportId" HorizontalAlign="Center" ShowHeader="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False" BorderStyle="None" GridLines="None">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="buttonLinks" CssClass="reportButton" Text='<%# Bind("RepName") %>' href='<%#String.Concat("ReportParams.aspx?reportId=") & Eval("ReportId")%>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                </ItemTemplate>
                <AlternatingItemTemplate></AlternatingItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <AlternatingItemTemplate>
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="buttonLinks" CssClass="reportButton" Text='<%# Bind("RepName") %>' href='<%#String.Concat("ReportParams.aspx?reportId=") & Eval("ReportId")%>' runat="server"></asp:HyperLink>
                </AlternatingItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

**CSS Code:**

```
.reportButton {
    display:block;
    height:25px;
    width:250px;
    background:#f1f1f1;
    padding:15px 10px 10px 10px;
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
    font-size:14px;
    text-align:center;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #e1e1e2;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

Example of what I'm getting:[image]

**I would like to see the gaps close on both sides and the right column to shift upward so that at least for this example, there is a clean 4 row by 2 column set of buttons.**

*I have considered just sticking two grids side by side and populating their data sets with the alternating records, but if I could stay away from that and maintain just one dataset I'd prefer that.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A GridView is rows based. So even the alternating template will be on a new row and thus below the previous hyperlink. So if you want data side by side better use a ListView.

```
<asp:DataList ID="DataList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="2" RepeatDirection="Horizontal">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Or if you use Bootstrap you could use a Repeater and the Bootstrap Grid System.

```
<div class="container">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink1" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6">
                    <asp:HyperLink ID="HyperLink2" runat="server">HyperLink</asp:HyperLink>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up going back to my query and adding a partition to get row numbers, then in the back-end code I just applied modular to get odd/even with two datasets. Put both grids in separate columns on the same row and took care of it. Thank you for the response though, this would of been my plan of attack had I not left for lunch and forgotten to check for an answer.